# Need help understanding the explanation Jurafsky & Martin give to a simple chatbot

Tags: python, regex, chatbot

I'm trying to work my way through *Speech and Language Processing* by Jurafsky & Martin. One of their exercises is to "Implement an ELIZA-like program, using substitutions." Their suggested answer is as follows:

```
import re, string
patterns = [
(r"\b(i’m|i am)\b", "YOU ARE"),
(r"\b(i|me)\b", "YOU"),
(r"\b(my)\b", "YOUR"),
(r"\b(well,?) ", ""),
(r".* YOU ARE (depressed|sad) .*",
r"I AM SORRY TO HEAR YOU ARE \1"),
(r".* YOU ARE (depressed|sad) .*",
r"WHY DO YOU THINK YOU ARE \1"),(r".* all .*", "IN WHAT WAY"),
(r".* always .*", "CAN YOU THINK OF A SPECIFIC EXAMPLE"),
(r"[%s]" % re.escape(string.punctuation), ""),
]
while True:
    comment = raw_input()
    response = comment.lower()
    for pat, sub in patterns:
        response = re.sub(pat, sub, response)
        print response.upper()
```

I don't see how this would work (and when I try it out in python, it doesn't) because it would just cycle through each tuple in patterns and if "pat" didn't match anything, it would just print out what the user inputted again and again...

I feel like there is probably a (semi) simple fix, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you sure you have the indentation right? If you dedent the `print` until after the `for` loop, it won't print out the input again and again, it'll just print the final output, which might be transformed by one of the patterns (or might just be the input uppercased, but that seems right for at least some inputs, like "Hello").

Comment: Still, some of those patterns seem pretty pointless. For example, the second `.* YOU ARE (depressed|sed) .*` can never trigger—if you type `Let me tell you what I am sad about`, after the first instance of that pattern it'll be `I AM SORRY TO HEAR YOU ARE SAD`, so the second instance won't match.

Comment: Oh, that makes total sense. That's not what they have in the answer I was looking at, but it must be a misprint. Thank you!

Comment: @abarnert that's a good point. I think this is supposed to be simple to a point where it wouldn't be that effective

Comment: @abarnert, wait actually I see what you're saying. I don't think it was designed to be that messed up...running the code, it seems like it only cycles through patterns until it finds a match. So "I am sad" spits out "YOU ARE SAD." Based on the code shouldn't it continue to run through...so "i am sad" ---> "YOU ARE SAD" ---> "I AM SORRY TO HEAR THAT YOU ARE SAD" ---> "I AM SORRY TO HEAR WHY DO YOU THINK YOU ARE SAD"

Which wouldn't make sense anyway. I'm assuming it stops after the first tuple that matches bc "sad" gets uppercased, which doesn't match the regex in the next one?

Comment: No, it doesn't stop after the first match. There's no code to do that (like a `break`). The only reason you don't get `YOU ARE sad` -> `I AM SORRY TO HEAR THAT YOU ARE sad` is that it doesn't match the pattern `.* YOU ARE (depressed|sad) .*`, because that pattern requires 0 or more characters _and a space_ before `YOU`, and likewise after `sad`, and the string doesn't have any such spaces.

Comment: But if you give it `Let me tell you what I am sad about`, that get lowercased, then transformed into `let me tell you what YOU ARE sad about`, and _that_ matches the pattern with spaces so it becomes `I'M SORRY TO HEAR THAT YOU ARE sad`, and that doesn't match the next pattern because there is no space after `sad`.

Comment: @abarnert ahhh, I see, I forgot about the white space. You're right tho...I don't see any way around the point that you bring up

Comment: Where does this code come from? Is it in the book, on the book's website, …? If there's something you can link to, there might be more context (or even errata). I notice that Jurafsky has [the entire current draft of the 3rd edition on his website](https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/), so it seems worth asking…

Comment: Also, if this _is_ in the book, there's an email address on the book's website for "typos and comments"—try writing to the authors and they'll probably either thank you for pointing it out or explain why it's not actually a bug.

Comment: It's from the "Instructor’s Solution Manual" for the second edition. So presumably they fixed the bug, but maybe still worth pointing out, good point